# нет привязки команды в checkBox-е

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

здравствуйте, нужно, чтобы параметром команды щелчка по checkbox был сам этот checkbox и возможно было в viewModel считать Uid этого checkbox. максимально упростил свой код...

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                         <CheckBox  Command="{Binding CheckBoxCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    Uid="{Binding Element.Id}"/>  <!--прибиндили к полю id поля Element из структуры из которых состоит Collection -->
               </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

RelayCommand:

```
public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<T> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("предикат не должен быть равным нулю");
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute((T)parameter);
    }


    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute((T)parameter);
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

viewModel:

```
class ViewModel 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// команда щелчка по checkbox
    /// </summary>
    private ICommand checkBoxCommand = null;
    public ICommand CheckBoxCommand
    {
        get 
        {
            if (checkBoxCommand == null)
            {
                checkBoxCommand = new RelayCommand<CheckBox>(AddData);
            }
            return checkBoxCommand; 
        }
    }

    private void AddData(CheckBox o)
    {
        var df = ((CheckBox)o).Uid;
        int brackPoint = 0;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// конструктор
    /// </summary>
    public ViewModel()
    {
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Element> Collection 
    {
       /**/
    }
```

}

Model(упрощенно):

```
Struct Element {
     public ObservableCollection<someClass> Collection
     { /**/ }

     public int Id { /**/ };
}
```

ставлю бряк в addData и щелкаю по checkBox - не заходит в addData, однако ошибок никаких нету... помогите решить проблему

Comment: Попробуйте так: `Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=DataContext.CheckBoxCommand}"`

Comment: `CommandParameter` вы уверены, что вам нужно передавать именно `CheckBox`? Вместо этого лучше передавать сразу `DataContext` : `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`, и тогда 
`private void AddData(Element o) {var df = o.UId; int brackPoint = 0; }`

Comment: омг... помогло добавить из первого сообщения код с AncestorType, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Привязывайтесь к контексту окна по имени. Вы переопределили контекст когда задали ItemSource.

```
<Window x:Name="Main" ...
<CheckBox  Command="{Binding DataContext.CheckBoxCommand, ElementName=Main}"...
```

Совет. Для того, чтобы сохранить изоляцию ViewModel от View рекомендую передавать в качестве параметра не `CheckBox`, а `Element`

```
 <CheckBox Command="{Binding DataContext.CheckBoxCommand, ElementName=Main}"
           CommandParameter="{Binding}"...
```

ViewModel:

```
checkBoxCommand = new RelayCommand<Element>(AddData);

private void AddData(Element e)
{
    var df = e.Id;
    ...
}
```

Comment: в моем случае Uid не может быть в свойствах viewModel Т.к. uid привязывается к полю структуры из которых состоит observablecollection, к которой, в свою очередь, привязывается listbox через itemssource... исправил условие вопроса с учетом реальности

Comment: @xperious ну так у вас привязка идет к элементам этой структуры. И `CheckBoxCommand` он тоже там ищет, а не во ViewModel

Comment: а как быть то? для окна this.DataContext = viewModel; стоит

Comment: @xperious обновил ответ

Comment: Такой код не будет работать ;)

Comment: да, не удалось... к тому же не понятно как Element передать

Comment: @xperious исправил, проверил, работает. По Element сейчас дополню

Comment: вам тоже спасибо за участие)