# Как передать путь в событие

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите как передать в событие путь к другому EXE-шнику.

Имеется:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel1" MouseLeftButtonDown="кнMouseLeftButtonDown">
    <Image x:Name="кн1" Height="64" Margin="0,10,55.8,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOr Source="рисунки/111.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="64"/>
    <Image x:Name="кн2" Height="64" Margin="0,10,55.8,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Source="рисунки/111.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="64"/>
    <Image x:Name="кн3" Height="64" Margin="0,10,55.8,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Source="рисунки/111.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="64"/>
    <Image x:Name="кн4" Height="64" Margin="0,10,55.8,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Source="рисунки/111.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="64"/>
    <Image x:Name="кн5" Height="64" Margin="0,10,55.8,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Source="рисунки/111.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="64"/>
    <Image x:Name="кн6" Height="64" Margin="0,10,55.8,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Source="рисунки/111.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="64"/>
    <Image x:Name="кн7" Height="64" Margin="0,10,55.8,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Source="рисунки/111.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="64"/>
    <Image x:Name="кн8" Height="64" Margin="0,10,55.8,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Source="рисунки/111.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="64"/>
    <Image x:Name="кн9" Height="64" Margin="0,10,55.8,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Source="рисунки/111.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="64"/>
    <Image x:Name="кн10" Height="64" Margin="0,10,55.8,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOr Source="рисунки/111.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="64"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Пути для каждой Image-кнопке хранятся в XML-ке `Knopki.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <Knopki>
    <nn>кн1</nn>
    <Название>xxx1</Название>
    <Видимость>true</Видимость>
    <Путь>C:\progi\xxx1.exe</Путь>
    <Иконка>xxx1.png</Иконка>
  </Knopki>
  <Knopki>
    <nn>кн2</nn>
    <Название>xxx2</Название>
    <Видимость>true</Видимость>
    <Путь>C:\progi\xxx2.exe</Путь>
    <Иконка>xxx2.png</Иконка>
  </Knopki>
  <Knopki>
    <nn>кн3</nn>
    <Название>xxx3</Название>
    <Видимость>true</Видимость>
    <Путь>C:\progi\xxx3.exe</Путь>
    <Иконка>xxx3.png</Иконка>
  </Knopki>
  <Knopki>
    <nn>кн4</nn>
    <Название>xxx4</Название>
    <Видимость>true</Видимость>
    <Путь>C:\progi\xxx4.exe</Путь>
    <Иконка>xxx4.png</Иконка>
  </Knopki>
  <Knopki>
    <nn>кн5</nn>
    <Название>xxx</Название>
    <Видимость>true</Видимость>
    <Путь>C:\progi\xxx5.exe</Путь>
    <Иконка>xxx5.png</Иконка>
  </Knopki>
</DocumentElement>
```

**Как при клике по `Image` передать сюда путь к EXE-шнику?**

```
private void MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( ??? );
}
```

Надо чтобы при нажатии на `Image` запускать разные EXE-шники для каждого `Image` свой, указанные в XML-ке.

Изменил. Cделал так — поменял `MouseButtonEventArgs` на `RoutedEventArgs`:

```
private void  кнMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    XDocument XMLdoc = XDocument.Load("Knopki.xml" );

     foreach (XElement kE in XMLdoc.Element("DocumentElement").Elements("Knopki"))
     {
         XElement nK = kE.Element("nn");
         XElement patch = kE.Element("Путь");

         if (nK.Value.ToString()  ==  ??????   ) {
             richTextBox1.AppendText("\n" + nK.Value.ToString() + "  " + patch.Value.ToString());
             System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( patch );
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечаю на свой вопрос, сделал вот так ,   работает

```
private void  кнMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        XDocument XMLdoc = XDocument.Load("Knopki.xml" );

        foreach (XElement kE in XMLdoc.Element("DocumentElement").Elements("Knopki"))
        {
            XElement nK = kE.Element("nn");
            XElement patch = kE.Element("Путь") ;

            if (nK.Value.ToString() == ((Image)e.OriginalSource).Name)
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(patch.Value.ToString());

        }
   }
```

Comment: Если кто подскажет как выполнить более оптимально,   например   как в одну строчку

Comment: Оптимально это выбросить то, что у вас есть сейчас и прислушаться к совету от @VladD

Answer (score 2):

Ваша задача прекрасно ложится на MVVM.

Для начала, VM. Вам нужно создать класс, описывающий один объект. Как-нибудь так:

```
class Entry
{
    public string Title { get; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; }
    public string ExecutablePath { get; }
    public string IconPath { get; }
}
```

В вашей модели вы должны прочитать XML, превратить каждый из тегов `Knopki` в экземпляр `Entry`, и сложить все `Entry` в коллекцию (хотя бы в `List<Entry>`).

Теперь, View. С ним всё просто. Поскольку вы отображаете список, вам нужен `ItemsControl`. За отображение отдельного элемента отвечает, понятно, `ItemTemplate`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding EntryCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Entry}">
            <Button>
                <Image Height="64" Width="64" Source="{Binding IconPath}" />
            </Button>
       <DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Чего у нас ещё нету, это реакции кнопок на нажатие. Для этого нужно подцепить к ним команду. Возьмите любую реализацию `RelayCommand` (например, [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/607945/10105)), путь для запуска передавайте как параметр. Итого:

```
<ItemsControl Name="MainContainer" ItemsSource="{Binding EntryCollection}">
```

и

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.InvokeExecute, ElementName=MainContainer}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ExecutablePath}">
```

Ну и вам нужна сама команда в главной VM:

```
ICommand InvokeExecute = new RelayCommand<string>(path => Process.Start(path));
```

Comment: VladD ,   спасибо  за  ответ,   но , 'Ваша задача прекрасно ложится на MVVM.'

Comment: VladD ,   спасибо  за  ответ,   но ,  может есть какой то путь чтобы привязать к каждой Image свой путь из XML-ки

Comment: Вы можете попробовать воспользоваться XmlDataProvider для того чтобы использовать xml вместо моделей. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749287(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Сделал изменения в методе кнMouseLeftButtonDown (см. посл.изм. в вопросе)    теперь осталось получить имя Image          пытаюсь   через  e.OriginalSource

Comment: @vova-forum: Вы пытаетесь писать на WPF как на WinForms. Так тоже можно, но качество кода получается хуже. Писать логику программы в обработчике клика как бы антипаттерн.

Comment: Полностью с вами согласен ,  но  патерны изучу чуть попозже , сейчас просто требовалось сделать как сделал ,  весь проект переделывать не смогу