# CommandManager выдает false для CanExecute, когда элемент с привязанной командой не находится на экране

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Проблема. Есть таблица с данными. Есть в каждой строке кнопочки с командами. в качестве параметров выступают объекты данных строк. Команды регистрирую через `CommandManager`. Так вот, когда я пролистываю вниз, некоторые команды, которые раньше были невидимы, оказываются неактивными. Причем `CanExecute` для них точно равно `True`, только оно не выполняется. При этом, если я выделю строку, то команды на ней становятся активными.

Я так понимаю, что `CommandManager` насильно делает их неактивными для экономии ресурсов, а в качестве `CanExecute` на всякий случай возвращает `False`. При этом почему то не все обновляет. Не делать же насильное обновление на каждое событие Scroll. Как отключить у CommandManager такую умность? :)

**UPD**

Отвечаю на вопрос по регистрации команд

```
var refreshCommand = new CommandBinding(Source.RefreshCommand);
refreshCommand.CanExecute += RefreshCommand_CanExecute;
refreshCommand.Executed += RefreshCommand_Executed;
CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(GetType(), refreshCommand);
```

Comment: А что означает «Команды регистрирую через CommandManager»? Можно код?

Comment: @VladD обновил вопрос

Comment: Скажите, а у вас `CanExecute` случайно не зависит от параметра? (Ну и если можно, сделайте минимальный воспроизводящий пример.)

Comment: @VladD, зависит, но я еще раз повторю, он не выполняется, когда элемент за пределами окна (скролла).

Comment: Ага, это важно. Насколько мне помнится, это было когда-то у меня источником проблем.

Comment: @VladD, не ну так то понятно, виртуализация и все такое, но когда айтем появляется в области видимости, почему `CanExecute` не обновляется? `CommandManager` же должен почти на любой чих пересматривать `CanExecute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982088/datagrid-wpf-virtualization-and-command-canexecute

Проблема в том, что при включенной виртуализации (а она включена по умолчанию), `CanExecute` не выполняется, а сразу устанавливается значение false. При этом `CommandManager` не обновляет состояние команд при прокрутке колесом мыши. Это и нужно заставить его сделать.

Автор предлагает сделать это через `AttachedProperty`

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandRefreshOnScrollingProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "CommandRefreshOnScrolling", 
            typeof(bool), 
            typeof(DataGridProperties), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnCommandRefreshOnScrollingChanged));

private static void OnCommandRefreshOnScrollingChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
      var dataGrid = d as DataGrid;
      if (dataGrid == null)
      {
          return;
      }
      if ((bool)e.NewValue)
      {
         dataGrid.PreviewMouseWheel += DataGridPreviewMouseWheel;
      }
}
private static void DataGridPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
     CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
}
```

Вот как использовать

```
<Setter Property="views:DataGridProperties.CommandRefreshOnScrolling" Value="True"></Setter>
```

Comment: `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested` — это довольно тяжёлое решение. Оно заставляет обновится _все_ команды. Так что имеет смысл спрофилировать.

Comment: @VladD, а как это сделать?

Comment: Проблема в том, что у вас нету `CanExecuteChanged`, и значит, нет простого метода сказать системе, что нужно перечитать `CanExecute`. Я бы использовал вместо одной команды + параметр просто подходящую реализацию `RelayCommand` (без `InvalidateRequerySuggested`).

Comment: @VladD, спасибо подумаю над этим во время рефакторинга

Comment: @VladD, что за RelayCommand? Меня сюда кидает https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.mvvm.relaycommand(v=vs.110).aspx но где взять требуемую библиотеку?

Comment: Не, это по идее не то. У нас пробегало по сайту несколько имплементаций. Иногда ещё называется `DelegateCommand`.  Сейчас поищу...

Comment: Например, вот тут есть: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/607945